# Hallucination and meditation

Tags: meaning, etymology, medical, psychology, psycholinguistics

Can we say that imagination in Meditation is a hallucination? When I imagine something in meditation can I hallucinate or hallucination is unconscious and meditation is a conscious experience . Meditation is conscious and hallucination is unconscious? Is this difference is correct or not? What is the clear difference between hallucination and imagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An hallucination is a false perception which occurs spontaneously. You cannot, and probably would not want to, summon an hallucination at will.

For instance if you were lying awake and the figure of your dead father appeared at the end of your bed that would be, according to your belief system, either an hallucination or a visit by the spirit of your father. In either case the appearence would be spontaneous. If, on the other hand, you were consciously trying to remember and/or visualise your father any image that arose would be a memory even it it was enormously vivid. If your belief system supported the  concept of summoning the spirit of the dead you might consider that you had summoned the spirit of your father but the appearance would not be an hallucination because you would have called it up deliberately

In meditation it is possible for images to arise spontaneously and they might be regarded as hallucinations but, because you would be aware that you were meditating and that the images would arise from the meditative state, I would say that they were not hallucinations.

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: now its clear that the main thing which differentiate among them is conscious and unconscious state .hallucination is unconscious experience and meditation is conscious experience